# Resample (bootstrap) data from matrix with x draws per row and y draws per column

Tags: r, nested, resampling

I have a matrix with zero's and one's. ~30% of the sample are 1s, I want to estimate a confidence-interval around this percentage (e.g., "if I sampled the whole population there would be likely 28-32% "1"s). For doing so you can bootstrap from the sample, (redraw the sample N times from itself with replacement and analyze the distribution of the percentage of 1s over all redrawn samples). However my data is nested (highly correlated) within rows and within columns. I tried out whether this nestedness makes a difference (since I have dichotmous variables I can use rflip() which simulates a biased coinflip), it does:

```
library("mosaic")

#### data example ####
c1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0) # high probability for "1"
c2<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) # low probability for "1"
d<-cbind.data.frame(c1,c2)

#### a) resample over entire data ####
b<-vector()
for (i in 1:10000){
b[i] <- rflip(20,      # Flip 20 times,  
              6/20)/   # Probability for "1": 6/20, i.e., probability for "0": 14/20
        20             # divide by 20 to return relative frequency
}

mean(b)# returns 0.3007955     # mean over 10000 replications: close to 6/20
sd(b)  # returns 0.1024339     # standard deviation important to compute confidence interval

#### b) resample per column ####
b1 <- vector()
b2 <- vector()
bt <- vector()
for (i in 1:10000){
  b1[i] <-  rflip(10,(5/10)) # Flip 10 times with probablility for c1
  b2[i] <-  rflip(10,(1/10)) # Flip 10 times with probablility for c2
  bt[i] <- (b1[i]+b2[i])/20  # sum up all 20 flips and divide by 20 to return relative frequency
}
mean(bt)# returns 0.3001475   # mean similar to a)
sd(bt)  # returns 0.09214384  # standard deviation smaller than a)
```

When I redraw 10 times from column c1 and 10 times from column c2 and replicate this process 10,000 times the distribution of the observed probabilities is more narrow than when I sample 20 times from the entire data. If the probability for "1" is identical in both columns approaches a) and b) lead to the same standard deviation.

I now want to consider not only the columns but also the rows, e.g. I want to draw 10 times from column 1 and 10 times from column 2 and I want to constrain that among these 20 draws there must be two draws per row. My first idea would be:

forloop{

1. Randomize order of columns
2. draw 10 times from column 1 but constrain that there are maximum 2 redraws per row
3. draw 10 times from column 2 but constrain that the redraws from column 1 plus the redraws from column 2 are maximum 2 redraws per row (if we had 2 redraws from row 1 for column 1, no redraws from row 1 for column 2)

}

Does anybody have an idea about how to do that or has anybody got a better idea? Must probably be a different function than rflip().
Would help me a lot!

Thanks,
ajj

Comment: `sd(bt) = sqrt((0.7*0.3 - var(c(0.5, 0.1))/2)/20) = 0.09219544`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_sum_variance_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `r2dtable`.

```
nrows <- 10L
ncols <- 6L
nr <- rep(ncols, nrows)
nc <- rep(nrows, ncols)

m <- r2dtable(1, nr, nc)[[1]]
m
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#>  [1,]    2    0    1    1    1    1
#>  [2,]    2    1    1    0    1    1
#>  [3,]    0    1    1    2    2    0
#>  [4,]    0    3    1    1    0    1
#>  [5,]    1    2    1    0    1    1
#>  [6,]    0    0    1    2    0    3
#>  [7,]    3    0    1    1    0    1
#>  [8,]    2    0    0    1    3    0
#>  [9,]    0    0    1    2    1    2
#> [10,]    0    3    2    0    1    0
rowSums(m)
#>  [1] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
colSums(m)
#> [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

> I want to draw 10 times from column 1 and 10 times from column 2 and I
> want to constrain that among these 20 draws there must be two draws
> per row.

That would be:

```
nrows <- 10L
ncols <- 2L
nr <- rep(ncols, nrows)
nc <- rep(nrows, ncols)

m <- r2dtable(1, nr, nc)[[1]]
m
#>       [,1] [,2]
#>  [1,]    2    0
#>  [2,]    0    2
#>  [3,]    1    1
#>  [4,]    2    0
#>  [5,]    0    2
#>  [6,]    2    0
#>  [7,]    1    1
#>  [8,]    1    1
#>  [9,]    0    2
#> [10,]    1    1
```

And you are correct about a smaller SD when the row/column counts are constrained when resampling:

```
broadcast <- Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "arma::cube broadcast(arma::cube& m, arma::mat& d) {return(m.each_slice() % d);}",
  depends = "RcppArmadillo",
  plugins = "cpp11"
)

c1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0) # high probability for "1"
c2 <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) # low probability for "1"
d <- cbind(c1, c2)
nr <- nrow(d)
nc <- ncol(d)
nreps <- 1e4L

bt <- colSums(
  broadcast(
    simplify2array(
      r2dtable(
        nreps,
        rep(nc, nr),
        rep(nr, nc)
      )
    ),
    d
  ),
  dims = 2
)/nr/nc
p <- mean(d)
mean(d) # true mean
#> [1] 0.3
mean(bt) # estimated mean
#> [1] 0.300685
sqrt(p*(1 - p)/nr/nc) # expected SD from uniform samples of size nr*nc
#> [1] 0.1024695
sqrt((p*(1 - p) - var(colMeans(d))*(1 - 1/nc))/nr/nc) # expected SD from column-wise resampling
#> [1] 0.09219544
sd(bt) # estimated SD from constrained row and column resampling
#> [1] 0.05604547
```

Comment: I misunderstood you, now I do, its perfect, thanks!

Comment: I added some code to show how to get your `bt` vector efficiently.

Comment: just wanted to post my own solution for the last step, completely different procedure but same results :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
sample(rep(1:10,2),size=10,replace=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice idea, it works for the first column! I am playing around / extending it so that it will work for further columns as well. In order to work for the second column for example I need to filter out values for those rows that have been drawn for the first column already.

Comment: @ajj This works for all columns

Comment: @ajj Think about it. You have two of each index. You take the total number of samples for the two columns combined. The first half are the indices for the first column. The second half for the second column. You can't get the same row more than twice.